# IE 8 flash not displaying

Tags: html, flash

I'm using flash in a few of my websites for displaying a slideshow. This is the code I use in [splendor-bg.com](http://splendor-bg.com) :

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" width="740" height="450" id="tech" align="middle">
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <param name="movie" value="splendor-bg.swf?xml_path=slides.xml" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <embed src="splendor-bg.swf?xml_path=slides.xml" quality="high" width="720" height="430" name="tech" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
    </object>
```

I can see it on my computer in internet explorer just fine (I must have installed something that is needed, or set up IE in some way, I guess).. but its not working on quite a few other computers I've tested it on - this is what they see:
[image: Flash not working]
Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this? Either a message of something that needs to be installed should be shown to the user, or something in the code itself.. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That white field isn't even recognized as flash - when I right click on it I don't get the flash menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem may be in this particular code.

However, I would like to suggest that you try swfobject. You can download it at http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

swfobject is a great way to embed flash to a website and seems to work in all browsers for me.

It's also very simple to use, let's assume you have a div container with the id flashcontent:

```
<div id="flashcontent">
</div>
```

And then with javascript you would simply do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {};
    var params = {allowScriptAccess: "sameDomain"};
    var attributes = {};
    swfobject.embedSWF("splendor-bg.swf?xml_path=slides.xml", "flashcontent", "720", "430", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

Voila and the Flash object should be embedded over the flashcontent div container.

Give it a try and see if it works better. You can read the swfobject documentation at http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation

Comment: This, combined with some troubleshooting in the IE worked. I guess the main problem is that the other systems are all 64-bit and there is no official version for flash in 64-bit windows. Had to download the "square" version for flash from adobe labs.

Comment: Weird, I have 64-bit Windows and never had any trouble viewing Flash. Hmms! But glad you solved it.

Comment: 32-bit flash works in 32-bit browsers on both x86 & x64 O/S. But if the browser is 64-bit you need 64-bit version of Flash Player. Though that doesn't explain why SWFObject fixed the problem.